# Decrypt function with securestring

Tags: c#, wpf, cryptography

So im dealing with problem. I have decrypt function which looks like this:

```
public static bool FileDecrypt(string inputFile, string outputFile, SecureString password)
    {

        byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
        byte[] salt = new byte[32];

        FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open);
        fsCrypt.Read(salt, 0, salt.Length);

        RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged();
        AES.KeySize = 256;
        AES.BlockSize = 128;
        var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, salt, 50000);
        AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
        AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);
        AES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        AES.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;

        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt, AES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);

        FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create);

            int read;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1048576];

            try
            {
                while ((read = cs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new ThreadStart(delegate { }));
                    fsOut.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
            }
            catch (CryptographicException ex_CryptographicException)
            {
                fsOut.Close();
                fsCrypt.Close();
                LogWriter loger = new LogWriter("Cryptography error: " + ex_CryptographicException.ToString());
                return false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                fsOut.Close();
                fsCrypt.Close();
                LogWriter loger = new LogWriter("Cryptography error: " + ex.ToString());
                return false;
            }

            try
            {
                cs.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                fsCrypt.Close();
                fsOut.Close();
                LogWriter loger = new LogWriter("Error when closing Cryptostream. Error: " + ex.ToString());
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                fsOut.Close();
                fsCrypt.Close();
            }

    return true;


    }
```

But i would like too use SecureString for password instead of just string if we talk about security.(People will input password for decrypting file so i dont wanna have it saved in memory in just normal string);
Problem is i really dont understand cryptography and its not my function and i dont wanna to mess anythin up.

If i wanna use Securestring as parameter i get:

```
 cannot convert from 'System.Security.SecureString' to 'char[]'
```

on:

```
byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
```

i guess i need to somehow convert it into Secure byte array (if that exists :D)

Can someone tell me how can i achieve that?  Or delete string from memory after usage would be enough?

Thanks and best regards,

John

//EDIT You can close the question i got answers in comments. Thanks

Comment: The above code does not include SecureString code. it contains only string for password. Please include the code that gives the error

Comment: Mind: _" Important: We don't recommend that you use the SecureString class for new development. For more information, see SecureString shouldn't be used on GitHub"_ from [SecureString Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) , also see https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md

Comment: `SecureString` is basically deprecated; it doesn't provide any useful security against any realistic attack - and more specifically: it **does not** reliably protect against the attack vector that people think it does, and any pretense that it does is just wishful thinking

Comment: _"People will input password for decrypting file so i don't wanna have it saved in memory in just normal string"_ how much more likely is it, that a password gets stolen by filming the keyboard or using a keylogger than an attacker actually messing with memory?

Comment: I guess youre right guys. Just deleting it from memory after usage. But then i really dont get point of even having SecureString

Comment: "But then i really dont get point of even having SecureString" - well, there isn't one - that's why it is basically deprecated and guidance is : not to use it

Answer (score 0):

In any case you need the bytes of the string to en- or decrypt them. Its possible to get them (look [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/107860/converting-a-securestring-to-a-byte-array)). Now you can pass the bytes to your encryption-method.

But this very complicated way does not improve your security. The commentators wrote it already - they are many more (and easier) ways to stole a password.

Just for fun: Maybe a hacker can somehow read RAM of a victim. Lets assume, that youre using the `SecureString` and crypt it. Your code is working and inside your methods its "safe". **But** wait - where does the user enters his password? In a textbox? Damn, it was in the RAM.
Somewhere in the RAM will be the password and you cant prevent that. This is not tragic - the password will be there only for a short time and the address (in RAM) will be never the same.

The costs for hacker/spyware that can read passwords out of RAM are extremely  high. So, the chance for attack on this way is very low.

And a last side note: Normally you doesn't en- or decrypt a password. You hash the password. https://www.wired.com/2016/06/hacker-lexicon-password-hashing/

#### Edit

Aw, never mind my last paragraph. I think you want to crypt password, but you are using it for your encryption. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are lot of answers for this if you google. However, I have been using one such method for couple of years. I got it somewhere from the internet and then modified to suit my need. For quick reference , see below. Credits goes to original author (whomever the person is).

You need to have references to below items:

```
 using System.Runtime.InteropServices; //You need reference to this item.
```

Method below:

```
 public static string unWrap(SecureString input_secure_string)
        {
            if (input_secure_string == null) return null;
            IntPtr _pointer = IntPtr.Zero; //Initiating a integer which can store a C++ pointer. Intptr is a type in C# which can store C or C++ pointer types.
            try
            {
                _pointer = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(input_secure_string); // Native code method which converts secure string to string
                return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(_pointer); 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally //Most important key part is this. After we return the converter string, we dispose the pointer from memory.
            {
                Marshal.ZeroFreeGlobalAllocUnicode(_pointer);
            }
        }
```